# android no resource found font family @font/your_font_xml

Tags: android, fonts, android-resources

I am trying to use Font as a Resource in XML instead of using 
Typeface.

I have kept `.ttf` files in `/res/font directory`.

I have implemented something like this

In `Layout XML`

```
<Button android:fontFamily="@font/my_font"/>
```

In res/font/font.ttf

```
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<font
    android:fontStyle="normal"
    android:fontWeight="40"
    android:font="@font/my_font" />
</font-family>
```

But still I am getting the error as below.

```
Error:(156, 33) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'fontFamily' with value '@font/font').`
```

I am referring [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html) and [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/font-resource.html) docs to implement this behavior.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you fix this issue? I am also facing the same issue in one of my application

Answer (score 1):

Try renaming your font into the ideal file name format, which is:

> All font names must be only: lowercase a-z, 0-9, or underscore.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your gradle version to 4.1

Do this by editing *gradle-wrapper.properties*

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
 <font
    android:fontStyle="normal"
    app:font="@font/rupee" //this line for below android 26 devices
    android:font="@font/rupee" />

  </font-family>
```

make sure this is correct and it should present in font folder and rebuild the project (invalidate caches/restart)

Comment: this solution is not working for me. Im getting error: Contents are not allowed in Prolog.

Answer (score -1):

You can change font location from

```
res/font directory
```

to

```
\assets\fonts
```

It worked for me, i hope it can help your problem

Comment: I think @Thientvse, u r not aware of Android 8 feature. Please visit link https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html

Answer (score -1):

You are making font folder inside **resource** .It is wrong .

You have to make font folder inside **asset**

Follow this Steps.

```
Right Click on app > New > Folder > Assets Folder
```

[image: Check This Image]

Comment: I think @Tej, u r not aware of Android 8 feature. Please visit link https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html